# how to build linux kernel with `allyesconfig` and debug information

Tags: linux-kernel, gnu-make, dwarf, debug-information

I want to build a linux kernel with as many C source files as possible for testing, so I use `make allyesconfig` at first. Meanwhile I need debug info, so I tried some ways to add it:

1. `make menuconfig` and open the debuginfo option.
2. modify the "CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_NONE=y" to "CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y"

and then run `make`, however an error happen for the both two ways:
"FATAL: modpost: vmlinux.o is truncated. sechdrs[i].sh_offset=572324920 > sizeof(*hrd)=64
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:56: vmlinux.symvers] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:1169: vmlinux] Error 2"

so I'm confused, how could I add debug info when I use the `allyesconfig`? The tested versions of my kernel is 6.0-rc6 and 6.0

Comment: Are you building 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: x86-64, and now I tried the latest 6.1.12, the error message is "objcopy: warning: vmlinux.o has a corrupt section with a size (8d23f823) larger than the file size
objcopy: warning: vmlinux.o has a corrupt section with a size (c987b988) larger than the file size
objcopy: warning: vmlinux.o has a corrupt section with a size (4bba10f9) larger than the file size
objcopy: vmlinux.o[.modinfo]: file truncated
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.vmlinux_o:72: modules.builtin.modinfo] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:1229: vmlinux_o] Error 2"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.